# Handle Navigation in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I think I am In little Trouble. I have 5 view controllers in my iPhone application. For example their name are like one, two, three, four and five and their navigation flow is like 1->2->3->4->5. Now my confusion is when I will click button in 5th view controller I want to see view number 3, but at that time when i will click back button it will go back to 5th view. I want 2 in place of 5. How can i do this? My code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SettingViewController *dealVC1 = (SettingViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dealVC1 animated:YES];
```

I am using code above for all navigation.

Comment: I can see two options for you:
1) when user presses the button on the 5th vc, pop to your 3rd vc instead of creating a new one.
2) do not use UINavigationViewController, but do all that staff yourself, and this way you will have control over all the navigation

Comment: Use custom back buttons Or unwind segue Or Handling manually your default back button

Comment: `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say all  your navigation controllers are  just `UIViewController` and their identifiers are `vc1` for first view controller  `vc2` for second etc.

Now let's say you are in 5th view controller and in your parent `UINavigationController.viewControllers` array you have: `[vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5]`. Now if you want to go back to 2nd view controller you should add this function in 5th view controller:

```
- (void)popTo2ndViewController {
    NSArray *controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    UIViewController *vc2 = controllers[1]; // If your viewControllers doesn't look like 1>2>3>4>5 here you may get an error.
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

To call this function you should override back button action as @iDeveloper has mentioned in his answer. When `popTo2ndViewController` will finish the `self.navigationController` array will look like: `[vc1, vc2]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by my comment :)

Comment: How can i use it in app delegate method? have you any idea?

Comment: In app delegate doesn't have `UINavigationController` but to create it you may do the same as you do with "SettingViewController". I made a simple code that may lead you: 
http://pastie.org/9637024 Good luck!

Comment: ohk thanks for your help :) nice to chat with you Szu

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `backButton` presented in left bar button of your navigation bar and define your own action to go either in 2nd or any view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Why to push on view controller 3? Instead pop to view controller 3, so on back of view controller 3, you will have view controller 2.

Loop through all view controllers in navigation controller. Put a condition for view controller 3, and just pop to that controller.

```
NSArray *arr = self.navigationcontrollers.viewcontrollers; 

for(int i = 0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
   if([arr objectAtIndex:i]isKindOgClass:[ViewController3 Class]]) {
      ViewController3 *v3 = (ViewController3 *)[arr objectAtIndex:3];
      [self.navigationcontroller popToConroller:v3 animated:YES];
      break;
   }
}
```

I am not sure, this will work with Storyboard or not. But try once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead going to your current number 3 view controller, push a **new** number 3 view controller into navigation stack and pass data you needed.

like 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3 , so push back in new number 3 will go back to 5 as you want.